# Office 365 Developer Subscription vs Enterprise E1

Tags: office-365

I don't have an MSDN subscription but can get an Office 365 developer subscription for $99.

For $8 per month, I can get an Office 365 Enterprise E1 subscription.

So these 2 options come out to similar cost.

It looks like I am able to deploy a developer site with the Enterprise E1 subscription.

So my question is, why would I ever pay $99 for the developer subscription when I can just get the E1 plan and deploy a developer site?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developer deal is more like the E3 license (for example, you get the office programs as well which you do not get in E1)

Developer license specifications:

> This customized Office 365 subscription includes all the tools and resources you need to jump in and start building apps:
>
> - SharePoint Online developer site, customized for creating and testing apps
> - You can install "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools, to create your first apps right within the browser
> - Office Professional Plus 2013
> - Exchange Online

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx#o365_signup

Comment: I checked out the link, which is the link I actually used to open a trial account last week. What's confusing is that it says I can provision an Office 365 Developer Site in a number of ways, including paying $99 outright, or if I already have other subscriptions, including E1 and E3. Does this imply that perhaps even with an E1 plan, I'd essentially be getting the same thing once I provision an Office 365 Developer site? VERY confusing!!!

Comment: Interesting point about Office Pro Plus 2013. I'd be curious about the SharePoint features. My impression was that the E1 plan includes "foundation" level features, similar to SP Online Plan 1 and that E3 includes "enterprise" level features, similar to SP Online Plan 2. I wonder what the developer subscription includes.

Comment: I'm essentially looking to do the following: 1) Gain better expertise on O365 and Apps 2) Showcase some of my work, mostly SharePoint related 3) Use some of the convenient "end-user" features of O365. It seemed like the developer subscription made sense, but then I began researching more about the various O365 plans and completely confused myself!

Comment: The developer site I have includes the Content by Search webpart, which the E1 license do not. So I'm pretty sure that the developer license is an E3 (at least when it comes to SharePoint features, and in that includes the Office license) with a pre-created developer site

Comment: So for $1 extra a year, you get more SharePoint features and the full Office Suite, pretty easy choice if you ask me! Even the fact that the dev site is recreated can be worth a dollar given the time saving ;)

Comment: Ah, OK. Sounds like the developer subscription is exactly what I need then. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I have just to switch from E1 to E3. The reason is I can't depoly an App which has SP2013 Workflow. The following error accures:

> @"Error 1
>           CorrelationId: 4ae4e796-fa47-465a-9ce3-d3bd55b698cf
>           ErrorDetail: There was an error during the operation.
>           ErrorType: Configuration
>           ErrorTypeName: Configuration
>           ExceptionMessage: An error occurred while attempting to execute a principal management operation.  Please contact your administrator.
>           Source: Common
>           SourceName: Common App Deployment

Without SP 2013 Workflow, the App works. It seems E1 is just a "Foundation" version.

Comment: Yeah the E1 license also doesn't include InfoPath services. It's pretty lame to be honest.